# Read data from file (as arrays) lines and do a comparison

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, git-bash

I have an issue and no idea which solution is better to use, I will describe my need first in order to explain it to you :

I have a text file, titled with a server name, example : server1.txt

Inside this file i have something like array (basically it's a check result):

```
cciex6:~/folder$
cciex6:~/folder$ cat server1
8 16 UP 10-6-2020-16:04
8 16 UP 15-6-2020-16:04
8 16 UP 20-6-2020-16:04
6 16 UP 25-6-2020-16:04
cciex6:~/folder$
```

8 : means 8 cores

16 : means 16 Gb of ram

UP : means ping successful, server is up

20-1-2020-16:04 : date of check and creation of the result.

---

I have some servers IPs in a servers.txt

2 scripts :

**first script**, will do a check for each server in the servers.txt, (check cpu cores, memory, up or down, and date of the check) store this infos in a server1 file

**second script** should read the lines from the server1 file, in do some comparison between new result (last line in the server1 file) and old result (line before last line) if it's the same results Nothing to do, in case memory increase or server DOWN, should give me alert in a log file or console or something.

for the first script, it's done i'm able to run it and get the information i need from the list of the servers

my issue is the second script, how can i read the RAM + CPU + UP or DOWN status, from the server1 file and make the comparison between last result and the result before the last one,

Any ideas please or help

really appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the last two lines of the file, and compare them, something like.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

file=server1.txt
declare -A old_result new_result
mapfile -t results < <(tail -n2 "$file")

read -r old_core old_ram old_status old_date <<< "${results[0]}"
read -r new_core new_ram new_status new_date <<< "${results[1]}"

old_result=(
  [core]="$old_core"
  [ram]="$old_ram"
  [status]="$old_status"
  [date]="$old_date"
)

new_result=(
  [core]="$new_core"
  [ram]="$new_ram"
  [status]="$new_status"
  [date]="$new_date"
)

for item in "${!old_result[@]}"; do
  [[ $item == date ]] && continue
  if [[ ${old_result[$item]} != ${new_result[$item]} ]]; then
    printf >&2 'old %s and new %s does not match!\n' "$item ${old_result[$item]}" "$item ${new_result[$item]}"
  fi
done
```

- It needs bash4+ because of mapfile and probably associative arrays.
- It skips the date but if you need to compare the date just comment out the date comparison or just delete that line.

---

Just using an associative array without `mapfile`.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

file=server1.txt
declare -A old_result new_result

{
  read -r old_core old_ram old_status old_date

  old_result=(
    [core]="$old_core"
    [ram]="$old_ram"
    [status]="$old_status"
    [date]="$old_date"
  )

  read -r new_core new_ram new_status new_date

  new_result=(
    [core]="$new_core"
    [ram]="$new_ram"
    [status]="$new_status"
    [date]="$new_date"
  )

} < <(tail -n2 "$file")

for item in "${!old_result[@]}"; do
  [[ $item == date ]] && continue
  if [[ ${old_result[$item]} != ${new_result[$item]} ]]; then
    printf >&2 'old %s and new %s does not match!\n' "$item ${old_result[$item]}" "$item ${new_result[$item]}"
  fi
done
```

---

Without `mapfile` and associative array, just using a while read loop.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

file=server1.txt

while read -r old_core old_ram old_status old_date; do
  read -r new_core new_ram new_status new_date
  if [[ $old_core != $new_core ]]; then
    printf >&2 'old core %s and new core %s does not match!\n' "$old_core" "$new_core"
  fi
  if [[ $old_ram != $new_ram ]]; then
    printf >&2 'old ram %s and new ram %s does not match!\n' "$old_ram" "$new_ram"
  fi
  if [[ $old_status != $new_status ]]; then
    printf >&2 'old status %s and new status %s does not match!\n' "$old_status" "$new_status"
  fi
done < <(tail -n2 "$file")
```

> should give me alert in a log file or console or something.

Pipe the script to `wall` which should work even invoke via `cron`, also it has some options that you can use.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if all you need to do is compare the last two lines.  Here's an awk script that does this:

```
awk ' { 
  line_prev = line_last ; 
  $4 = ""
  line_last = $0 
}
END {
  if (line_prev && line_prev != line_last || line_last ~ /DOWN/ ) { 
    print "Alert!", FILENAME, line_prev, "--->",  line_last
  }
}' "$1"
```

The script, let's call it ./second_script, can be invoked like this:

```
./second_script server1
```

You can pipe the output to syslog so that you could receive an alert.

```
./second_script server1 | logger "<add-your-favorite-syslog-parameters here>"
```